# Performing an event on a a text area input when spacebar is pressed with Javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox, dom-events, javascript-objects

I'm trying to mimic the tags feature on Stack Overflow where when you click the <kbd>space</kbd> button on the text box, it adds a blue border to the previous text in the `textbox` and adds an <kbd>X</kbd> button besides it to remove it if wanted.

Here is an image example of what I'm trying to do:

[image].

Here is what I have so far. If someone can help me, I would really appreciate it.

```
<input id="tags"> 

<script>

document.getElementById("tags").addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 32) {
       // what do I fill in here??
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at what the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="js-tag-editor tag-editor multi-line s-input" style="padding: 0px 9.1px; box-sizing: border-box; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; width: 100%;">
    <span><span class="s-tag rendered-element">javascript<a class="js-delete-tag s-tag--dismiss" title="Remove tag"><svg class="svg-icon iconClearSm pe-none" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
            <path d="M12 3.41L10.59 2 7 5.59 3.41 2 2 3.41 5.59 7 2 10.59 3.41 12 7 8.41 10.59 12 12 10.59 8.41 7z">
            </path>
          </svg></a></span>
      <span class="s-tag rendered-element">arrays<a class="js-delete-tag s-tag--dismiss" title="Remove tag"><svg class="svg-icon iconClearSm pe-none" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
            <path d="M12 3.41L10.59 2 7 5.59 3.41 2 2 3.41 5.59 7 2 10.59 3.41 12 7 8.41 10.59 12 12 10.59 8.41 7z">
            </path>
          </svg></a></span>
      <span class="s-tag rendered-element">javascript-events<a class="js-delete-tag s-tag--dismiss" title="Remove tag"><svg class="svg-icon iconClearSm pe-none" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
            <path d="M12 3.41L10.59 2 7 5.59 3.41 2 2 3.41 5.59 7 2 10.59 3.41 12 7 8.41 10.59 12 12 10.59 8.41 7z">
            </path>
          </svg></a></span>
      <span class="s-tag rendered-element">javascript-objects<a class="js-delete-tag s-tag--dismiss" title="Remove tag"><svg class="svg-icon iconClearSm pe-none" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
            <path d="M12 3.41L10.59 2 7 5.59 3.41 2 2 3.41 5.59 7 2 10.59 3.41 12 7 8.41 10.59 12 12 10.59 8.41 7z">
            </path>
          </svg></a></span>
    </span>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="103" placeholder="" id="tageditor-replacing-tagnames--input" class="s-input js-tageditor-replacing" style="width: 19px;"><span></span>
  </div>
```

It's `<span>`s followed by an input. It looks to the user a bit like the input is actually the whole line, but it's not - the input is only the section on the right that's typable.

To add a border, use CSS. To remove an appended element, call `.remove()` on it. Something like:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode === 32) {
    const span = input.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', document.createElement('span'));
    span.textContent = input.value;
    const x = span.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
    x.textContent = 'x';
    x.onclick = () => span.remove();
    input.value = '';
  }
});
```

```css
.tag-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.tag-container span {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.tag-container span button {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.tag-container input:focus, .tag-container input {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-container">
  <input>
</div>
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I want when you click space, the text beforehand needs to remain in the text-box, not create a whole different span element. My application has a submit button and the information needs to stay in the text-box in order to be moved to the database. Any idea on how to do the same thing as you wrote above, but make it stay in the text box?

Comment: The text box value needs to be cleared for the span to be inserted sensibly. It's trivial to retrieve the text from the spans later. `[...document.querySelectorAll('.tag-container span')].map(span => span.textContent).join('')` Don't try to keep the text that's now in the spans too in the text box.

Comment: There is an image I put along with my question that shows how I wanted it to be. Is there any possible way to do that? It's how its done in stack overflow when someone wants to add tags to a question

Comment: The code in my question produces a framework of the basics for that - press "Run code snippet" to see it working. It's not an exact replica, but it's all the functionality you need, and the basics of the CSS. If you want to add onto it and make it more elaborate, like adding a SVG to the spans or something, feel free.