# How do I dynamically style a word as it is typed on a text area?

Tags: javascript

I have a text area where a user is asked to input one or more words like: 'Banana Apple Orange...'.

I want the words to have a certain style, like a border and or a background color after you hit the space bar.

**Like the 'Tags' section on this page....**

I've looked around for JS scripts to do this but couldn't quite find what I was looking for.

Comment: What solutions have you already tried? Including relevant code in your question makes it easier for people to help you. You might want to read this page about [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think after the hitting the space character you can get the value and add it to an array then inside that textarea you could iterate on the array and add the specific class into that tag.

Comment: In a `<textarea>` tag? AFAIK you still can’t do that. If you want a WYSIWYG JS editor you’re likely better off using an existing library/module.

Comment: This is what I'd like to accomplish https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67798601/performing-an-event-on-a-a-text-area-input-when-spacebar-is-pressed-with-javascr

Comment: you want to achieve tags in the taxarea correct?

Comment: @AbuSufian that's right

Comment: you can use jquery plugin like the on in this link  https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

Comment: wondering if you might be looking for something like the `contenteditable` attribute.

Comment: https://googlethatforyou.com?q=vanilla%20javascript%20tags%20input